# Is there a function like ExtractIconEx but for in-memory data instead of from a file

Tags: windows, winapi, shell32, shell32.dll

In the [zserge/tray](https://github.com/zserge/tray/blob/master/tray.h) project, in the [windows tray_update function](https://github.com/zserge/tray/blob/master/tray.h#L334), the `ExtractIconEx` function is used to construct the icon handle (`HICON icon`). The function is passed `tray->icon` as the first argument, which is a string that points to a `.ico` file.

My question is, is there a function to get an icon handle using data from a variable (i.e. storing the binary of the `.ico` file in an array)?

Example of storing file data in array:

```c
unsigned char rawIconData[] = {
  0x12, 0x34, // ...
};
```

Comment: Why are you putting it in an array instead of inside your own code's resources?

Comment: @BenVoigt not sure what you mean, what is my codes resources?

Comment: The whole point of the resource compiler and resource access APIs are so that binaries (like DLLs and EXEs) can contain both the code and the artwork that the code needs, in a single file, to make deployment easy.

Comment: @BenVoigt I'm new to the win api stuff, do you know of a guide or tutorial that would help me with this?

Comment: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/menurc/about-resource-files gives a nice overview and the tutorials I found were pretty bad.  I may look some more after work.

Answer (score 1):

There is `CreateIconFromResourceEx`, but it will only give you one icon size (you can choose which) instead of returning an array of icons as `ExtractIconEx` does.